# How do I join multiple searches in just one query?

Tags: sql

I have four searches to do, but instead of doing it separately I would like to make just one in a row.
Could someone help me please?
Here is the following querys:

Number1

```
select ATIVO,'' VENCIMENTO, QUANTIDADE ,PRECO,'' CODFAR,'' 
       FINANCEIRO,'','','','',CLASSIFICACAO 
FROM srf_operacoes WHERE data = to_date ('14/06/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

Number 2

```
select ATIVO,'' VENCIMENTO, QUANTIDADE ,PRECO,'' CODFAR,'' 
       FINANCEIRO,'','','','',CLASSIFICACAO 
FROM ativos WHERE data = to_date ('14/06/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

Number 3

```
select ATIVO,'' VENCIMENTO, QUANTIDADE ,PRECO,'' CODFAR,'' 
       FINANCEIRO,'','','','',CLASSIFICACAO 
FROM srf_base WHERE data = to_date ('14/06/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

Number 4

```
select ATIVO,'' VENCIMENTO, QUANTIDADE ,PRECO,'' CODFAR,'' 
       FINANCEIRO,'','','','',CLASSIFICACAO 
FROM ativos_rf WHERE data = to_date ('14/06/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

Comment: You will get better responses if you take some time to properly indent your queries.

Comment: A simplified example would help too.  That's a lot to look through.

Comment: I've just edited it, it's easier now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for an union all:

```
select ATIVO,'' VENCIMENTO, QUANTIDADE ,PRECO,'' CODFAR,'' FINANCEIRO,'','','','',CLASSIFICACAO FROM ativos WHERE data = to_date ('14/06/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
union all
select ATIVO,'' VENCIMENTO, QUANTIDADE ,PRECO,'' CODFAR,'' FINANCEIRO,'','','','',CLASSIFICACAO FROM srf_base WHERE data = to_date ('14/06/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
union all
select ATIVO,'' VENCIMENTO, QUANTIDADE ,PRECO,'' CODFAR,'' FINANCEIRO,'','','','',CLASSIFICACAO FROM srf_operacoes WHERE data = to_date ('14/06/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
union all
select ATIVO,'' VENCIMENTO, QUANTIDADE ,PRECO,'' CODFAR,'' FINANCEIRO,'','','','',CLASSIFICACAO FROM ativos_rf WHERE data = to_date ('14/06/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
```